# Flex: how to flatten loaded swf and then apply alpha, rather than applying alpha and then flattening

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash, alpha

I have a flex application and am trying to show some animated vector shapes on a google map. To do this I load an external SWF (the content is dynamic, so I have to load at runtime and SWF was the only loadable format supporting animation AFAIK) and place it on the map using an overlay.

I then need to control the alpha of the SWF. Setting it is straightforward, but for some reason the alpha appears to be applied to the sub-shapes inside the SWF, and only after that is the image composited onto the map. This makes the yellow blob that is on top of the green blob appear yellow-green rather than just yellow.

I need to somehow tell flex/flash to "render/flatten the SWF, then apply the alpha", rather than "apply the alpha to the individual sub-shapes, then flatten to the map". Ideally without going via e.g. a BitmapData object or similar.

The containment hierarchy is Map -> BlobManager -> Loader -> Loader.content (the SWF) and I've tried applying the alpha to the BlobManager, Loader, and Loader.content separately, but no difference. I've tried cacheAsBitmap on the lower layers and then applying alpha higher up to no avail.

Any suggestions for what to try next? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [BlendMode.LAYER](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html#LAYER), it saved many lives.

Comment: Thx @alxx, if that works then ignore my answer :) And I've learned something new too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that without drawing the loaded content on a Bitmap and using that to display with alpha.
It is quite easy though, although you might run into security violations if the loaded content is from another domain and won't let you create bitmapData from it.

```
// content is the loaded external swf, or the Loader itself?
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(content.width, content.height);
bitmapData.draw(content);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
bitmap.alpha = .5;
addChild(bitmap);
```

It may not even be necessary to display the loaded content (although I haven't tried that) and you can also take only part of it to use as bitmapData using a Matrix.

EDIT: for animation, another option is to load an animated gif as described here: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=95 (I have no experience with it so I can't say if it'd really work for you), or use video.

Comment: As far as I understand from question the main problem is that loaded content is animation :(